# The method '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: dart

I'm trying to count the words within a given string and return a `Map` of the results.
My code follows:

```dart
class WordCount {
  Map<String, int> countWords(String s) {
    var out = <String, int>{};
    var words = s.split(" ");
    for (var word in words) {
      if (out.containsKey(word)) {
        out[word] += 1;
      } else {
        out[word] = 1;
      }
    }
    return out;
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following build error on the line `out[word] += 1;` and I'm not sure how to work around it:

```
The method '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').dart(unchecked_use_of_nullable_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of *value* of the map `out` is `int` and not `int?`. Now you are definitely sure that it can't be *null*. So, you can use the `!` to tell Dart that this  cannot be null.

```
Map<String, int> countWords(String s) {
    var out = <String, int>{};
    var words = s.split(" ");
    for (var word in words) {
      if (out.containsKey(word)) {
        //edit this line
        out[word] = out[word]! + 1;
      } else {
        out[word] = 1;
      }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `[]` operator on `Map` returns the value associated with the key, or `null` if no value is associated with that key. That makes the result *nullable*, in your case the type is `int?`. A nullable type might be `null`, and therefore you can't just call `+` on it with the Dart null safety feature enabled.

In your case, you first check whether the map contains the key, then read the value out. You know that the value won't be `null`, so you could add the `!` operator after the read, `out[word]!`, and know that it won't throw.

However, you could also just read the value and check whether it's `null` instead of first checking whether it will be there, and then reading the value. I'd change the code to:

```dart
  Map<String, int> countWords(String s) {
    var out = <String, int>{};
    var words = s.split(" ");
    for (var word in words) {
      out[word] = (out[word] ?? 0) + 1;
    }
    return out;
```

Comment: Really wish there was a way to use the bang operator for `+=` (etc) operations.

Answer (score -1):

If you are guarantee that `out[word]` will never be null, then you can just set your code like this:

```dart
if (out.containsKey(word)) {
  out[word]! += 1;
} else {
  out[word]! = 1;
}
```

This error is triggering because you are using dart with null-safety enabled, so if your datatype is nullable and you don't have safe manipulation, then you should use the "?" operator after a variable call

Comment: Sadly, neither of those assignments work. The latter one doesn't need, and won't accept, the `!` - an expression ending in `!` is not an assignable expression. The former isn't currently accepted, for the same reason, although it would be awesome if it was (q.v., https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1113).